# How to do a Bounding Box in XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, xna, collision, bounding

So I need to create a bounding box for a cube I've got in XNA 4.0.  I know how to create a bounding sphere, but the problem is, the BoundingBox is not stored in the mesh like the BoundingSphere is.  I am also very new to XNA and programming in general, so a really beginner-friendly step by step tutorial would be best.

Answer (score 0):

Is the cube hat you have got a loaded Mesh? If so maybe this is what you're looking for: http://www.toymaker.info/Games/XNA/html/xna_bounding_box.html